# Rails undefined method error for a column that was removed from a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I removed the 'cuisine' column from my 'restaurants' table and now my form for creating or editing a restaurants gives me an undefined method for cuisine error.  Here is an example from the rails console.

```
irb(main):002:0> restaurant = Restaurant.new
irb(main)<Restaurant id: nil, name: nil, rating: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, latitude: nil, longitude: nil, address: nil, owner_id: nil>
irb(main):003:0> restaurant.save
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
NoMethodError: undefined method `cuisine' for #<Restaurant:0x007f9b0c258e20>
    from (irb):3
irb(main):004:0>
```

Here is my schema for restaurants:

```
create_table "restaurants", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "rating"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.float "latitude"
    t.float "longitude"
    t.string "address"
    t.bigint "owner_id"
    t.index ["owner_id"], name: "index_restaurants_on_owner_id"
  end
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the restaurant model was still trying to validate the presence of cuisine.